# Function is returning value but variable it returns it into doesn't hold that value. Why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

When debugging I found that on this line of code:

```
String profileId = ((GlobalApplicationClass) getApplication()).getProfileId();
```

On the watch tab, `((GlobalApplicationClass) getApplication()).getProfileId()` returned the right value.
However, on the watch tab , profileId was `""`  (as is its initialised value in the GlobalApplicationClass).

This code was working fine and profileId was being populated with the correct value.

Now, I do not understand why it's not getting populated. Why would calling the function return the right value but then it passes its initialised value into the profileId variable?

Comment: Are you watching the variable while the debugger is still on that line? Because if that's the case the value has not been set yet. You'll have to wait till the line is executed (i.e., step to the next instruction).

Comment: No, I did step to the next function and profileId remained as "". I was investigating it because I pass profileID into another method later and its "" at that point too.

Comment: *I did step to the next function* - did profileId go out of scope?   But assuming the statement actually completes, it is vanishingly improbable that the right-hand side of an assignment does not set the left-hand variable, so the conclusion is there's something wrong with your tools or the way you're using them.

Comment: Sorry i mistyped, I meant "I did step to the next line" . And no the profileId did not go out of scope.

Comment: Its not about the tools, because profileId gets persisted in my database where it is "" at that point too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was the problem. I will post the answer in case anyone in future encounters a similar problem. But after that particular line of code, I then executed a code that would be run on a different thread.

Upon debugging the debugger wasn't able to properly step over the population of profileId because it would step to the code block that would execute on a different thread.

When that thread would try to use profileId, it would take it as "" because that would be the value of it when the thread started running and the value of it when the code in the thread would need to use it.

The solution would be to start the thread once profileId is populated.

Comment: Ah, so a good old race condition. Nice :)